# How to make a responsive centered div follow the viewport?

Tags: css, angular

I want to make a `div` that follows the viewport. I am not able to use fixed positioning. For some reason the `div` doesn't follow the viewport properly, it always 'lags' behind, especially when changing scroll direction. You can see what I mean on plunker [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/8QLemNhAD8oYHlLqLkOb/).

That is the first part of the problem. The second is that I need the div to immediately move into the viewport when it appears. (Clicking anywhere in the output panel in the plunker will toggle the div to appear). The *ngIf part of the appearing is important because in my actual app I am using a component with entry animations instead of a div, so no `[hidden]` I'm afraid.

**So why can't I use `fixed` positioning?**
Basically, fixed positioning causes the element to calculate the width differently to its sibling elements when the viewport contains scrollbars. I also can't use the `overflow: scroll` trick on the element because it has shadows that get clipped by the viewport. It also looks ugly having two scrollbars.

Comment: Is there any reason that responsive design does not work for your requirements?

Comment: @ochi I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Also I don't understand why I got downvoted.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You seem to be wanting to do something that responsive design (and patterns) are good at.  You likely got downvoted for not adding an [mcve] to your question (external links can be dead at any given time - read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a fixed centered div in a wrapper using flex.
[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/82b3c896/1/)

```
   #wrapper{
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:fixed;
        display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
      }
      #my-app{
        position:relative;
        width:50%;
       height:50%;
        background-color:green;
      }



  <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="my-app">
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Ok, so the reason why using fixed positioning won't work: try to center the wrapper in the scrollview viewport. It will always be off-centre because of how fixed positioning is calculated

Comment: Yes exactly! :) Thank you very much. You deserve to be picked as answer.

Comment: @Campbell Thanks, Google flex and your life will be much better XD

Comment: @Campbell https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/